# Why does web3.eth.getAccounts() return only 1 account?

Tags: web3js

I would expect this to return 10 accounts but I get only 1.

```
const provider = new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://rinkeby.infura.io/ll2k3jdlKDl")
    web3 = new Web3(provider)
    Promise.promisifyAll(web3.eth)
    let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccountsAsync()
```

Can anyone explain why? or how I can get more accounts on there. 
My understanding is that the other 9 accounts should be derived from my mnemonic. Is Infura not doing that for some reason?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using [`truffle-hdwallet-provider`](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider), the documentation says this:

> By default, the `HDWalletProvider` will use the address of the first
>   address that's generated from the mnemonic. If you pass in a specific
>   index, it'll use that address instead. **Currently, the `HDWalletProvider`**
>   **manages only one address at a time**, but it can be easily upgraded to
>   manage (i.e., "unlock") multiple addresses.

**EDIT**

Actually, it looks like this has already been done. See https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider/blob/master/index.js#L10:

```
function HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, provider_url, address_index=0, num_addresses=1) {
```

It looks like you can just pass a fourth parameter. E.g.

```
new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://rinkeby.infura.io/ll2k3jdlKDl", 0, 10)
```

Comment: Do you know how to "unlock" multiple addresses? The documentation is not clear to me. Or an alternative to HDWalletProvider if its impossible?

Comment: See my edit. It looks like someone already did that.

Comment: This looks like the commit that added support for multiple accounts, but the README was not updated: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider/commit/f930cc84550f8c10cffb81d44fde65fe4defce03.

Comment: Thanks, if anyone is wondering i copied and pasted that into my node_modules/truffle-hdwallet-provider/index.js and it worked!

Comment: The issue is that the GitHub code is updated to support multiple accounts, but npm has not been updated. 

@tedoland instead of changing the code, try this: 

npm install --save-dev git+https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider.git#71520a2

Comment: The third parameter just sets the default account, but all accounts should be unlocked.