# how to make getAccounts() return a list of all 10 accounts?

Tags: web3js, truffle, accounts

I am using Truffle Development (or Ganache at times) and the problem is `web3.eth.accounts` is only one account and not the list of all 10 accounts

I want to get hold of at least first two so that I can do token transfer (ERC721) using `safeTransferFrom`

For now I have just hardcoded the second parameter (to account) and that works, but every time I switch Development to Ganche I have to recode the second account, which is not nice.

I have tried all kinds of ways for `getAccounts` (callback or promise) but no use.

For example:

```
web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
  this.setState( {accounts : accounts} );
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that this is the same problem from here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41283/why-does-web3-eth-getaccounts-return-only-1-account

Comment: Shawn, yes I had seen the thread you are pointing to. But that thread is about using HDWalletProvider and says only 1 account is returned. I am not sure if HDWalletProvider is used internally, and hoping that there is some better way to get around this limitation of 1 account. If HDWalletProvider is the only way, then YES this is same thread. But I want some authority to say if HDWalletProvider is the only way.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the accounts by writing an async function, and using await, like this:

```
async function yourFunc() {
    const provider = ganache.provider();
    const web3 = new Web3(provider);
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        console.log('account['+i+']: '+accounts[i]);
}

yourFunc().then();
```

FYI: If what you're trying to do is deploy a contract to the ganache provider for local testing, I've posted [a fully working code sample here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/67911/44608). Please upvote if this helps you.